# Como exportar dados do banco de dados, gerar um csv e efetuar o download?

Tags: java, txt

Possuo uma tela de vendas, aonde usuário seleciona um cliente, um produto, a quantidade e efetua a compra, essas informações são gravadas no banco de dados. Preciso de um botão na tela de vendas que gera um relatório com todas as vendas em csv

Comment: Estou usando Java e Spring boot

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito prático seria fazer

```sql
SELECT * FROM vendas INTO OUTFILE 'C:/vendas.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

o `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','` determina a separação das colunas com uma "," (pode ser substituido)

o `ENCLOSED BY '"'` encapsula os dados com aspas duplas (pode ser substituido ou ignorado)

e o `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` especifica que cada linha termina com uma quebra de linha